# Nesting jQuery animation

Tags: jquery

I have tab schema that it´s working nicely but I want a info div to appear inside every tab for a couple of seconds and slide away without any interaction. This is my tabs script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#temascont").find("[id^='cont']").hide(); // Hide all tabs
$("#menucont li:first").attr("id","actual"); // Activate first tab
$("#temascont #cont0").fadeIn(); // Display the first tab's contents
$('#menucont a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "actual"){ // Find the actual tab
     return;
    }
    else{
      $("#temascont").find("[id^='cont']").hide(); // Hide all the content
      $(this).parent().attr("id","actual"); // Activate the actual Div
      $("#menucont li").attr("id",""); //Resetting all id's
      $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for the actual tab
    }
});
});
```

So far so good, Now this is the animation that I want to nest.

```
$(".addsmin").delay( 1500 ).animate({left:"-200"},{duration:300});
```

If I put it at the start of the initial function it appears only once when I click on any of the tabs containing the transitional div (.addsmin) and the same happens if put it inside the else brackets.

What say You, is this possible?

Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/roec4h4z/

Comment: please clarify the question, it's so unclear!

Comment: When you have a JavaScript question it's awesome if you can provide a jsFiddle with a working example (attempt or just boilerplate) for us to start tweakng.

Comment: :) Thank You, here's the Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/roec4h4z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the left property on every click:
http://jsfiddle.net/roec4h4z/2/

```
 $(".addsmin").delay( 1500 ).css("left", "0").animate({left:"-200"},{duration:300});
```

Also, when you use **$(".addsmin")**, you actually selects all .addsmin on the page.. you should only animate the one inside the "actual" div you clicked.

Comment: Whao, didn't see that coming :) excelent answer... Thank YOu that was it.